# Multiple inline editing for Sencha GXT grid?

Tags: java, gwt, extjs, gxt

Need to make edititing for every cell in row  by clicking on any cell of that row. I know about `GridRowEditing` , but I need to make something like `GridInlineEditing` for **every** cell in row at the same time. Is that possible?

Comment: Do you need `GridRowEditing` along with `GridInlineEditing`?

Comment: I suppose, you do not want to display the buttons in GridRowEditing.
You can try, extend the gridRowEditing class, override createRowEditor and hide the buttons. See the class, how they have implemented it. Or, you can create the complete functionality just by looking at how they created it